# Having an issue with duplicate entries in exported file

Tags: c#, winforms, import, export

I have an application where I have the 3 tables whose structure is as below:

```
1) Program
   --------
   Program_ID
   Description

2) SubProgram
   ----------
   SubProgram_ID
   Program_ID
   Description 

3) Tuning
   --------
   Tuning_ID
   SubProgram_ID
   Program_ID
   Description
```

Ex. Table Values:

Program:

```
Program_ID   Description
------------------------
1            ABCD
```

SubProgram

```
SubProgram_ID    Program_ID   Description
-----------------------------------------
1                1            EFGH
2                1            IJKL       // Here is the problem
3                1            IJKL       // Here is the problem
```

Tuning

```
Tuning_ID  SubProgram_ID  Program_ID Description
--------------------------------------------------
1          1              1          MNOP
2          2              1          QRST
3          1              1          UVWX
```

Now I have a module where I can export that records in XML file and any one can import that again in their software where the Primary Key may differ.

Exported XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
<Program>
   <Program_ID>123</Program_ID>
   <Description>ABCD</Description>
</Program>
<SubProgramList>
<SubProgram>
   <SubProgram_ID>1195</SubProgram_ID>
   <Descr>EFGH</Descr>
</SubProgram>
<SubProgram>
   <SubProgram_ID>1195</SubProgram_ID>
   <Descr>IJKL</Descr>
</SubProgram>
<SubProgram>
   <SubProgram_ID>1195</SubProgram_ID>
   <Descr>IJKL</Descr>
</SubProgram>
<SubProgramList>

<TuningList>
<Tunings>
   <Program_ID>True</Program_ID>
   <SubProgram_ID>0</SubProgram_ID>
   <Description>MNOP</Description>
</Tunings>
<Tunings>
   <Program_ID>True</Program_ID>
   <SubProgram_ID>0</SubProgram_ID>
   <Description>QRST</Description>
</Tunings>
<Tunings>
   <Program_ID>True</Program_ID>
   <SubProgram_ID>0</SubProgram_ID>
   <Description>UVWX</Description>
</Tunings>
</TuningList>
</DocumentElement>
```

So My problem is:
I insert the records based on Description so When SubProgram have the same description then the `Tunings` under that subprogram will be inserted in the only one subprogram and not been created the second one.

**How can I identify the parent subprogram of the perticular tuning while Importing.?**

So how can I solve the issue.??

Comment: Please explain the question more, do you want to prevent duplicates by locating the pre-existing entry with matching description and use the entry id, or you are already trying that and not succeeding?

Comment: Yes..If I use the entry id of the record but it may not be there if some other people will import in their software..so that was the issue..How can I identify the `parent subprogram` of the perticular `tuning`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a design decision - it may differ based on your business needs, but in general it should look like the following:

- you should have a center point where you import the data to make sure that duplicate check is made in sequence not in parallel, else you will need a time stamp field to sync the data based on order of creation
- you should check if the are any duplicate records in the imported data, duplicate descriptions or duplicate ids and clear those or return a validation exception
- If you have the rule(No duplicate description) for all levels (Program,SubProgram,Tunning) then you should first check if the program is duplicate(by comparing the description with existing data) if yes get the id from the database and put it in a mapping dictionary

  ```
  var ProgramIdMapping = new Dictionary<int,int>();
  ProgramIdMapping.Add(ImportedDataId, DatabaseId);
  ```
- Now repeat this for the subprograms and the tuning records, and when you start inserting them into the database you locate the parent database Id from the mapping dictionary

  ```
  var DbProgramId = ProgramIdMapping[subProgram.ProgramId];
  ```